# What about "Questions" that are clearly not questions?

Tags: discussion

This question https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/6036/large-hadron-collider-sounds-and-music was in the review queue.  It was flagged as 'not a question.'

There is no question that this is not a question (pardon the pun), but it's also not the only one I've seen on SD in this vein.  This variety has apparently not been a problem in the past here.  This one in particular has been on the site for a couple years, has garnered a fair number of upvotes, and was only *just* flagged.

As the site moves forward, should there be any adjustment to whether or not these *non*-questions are acceptable?

Personally, this strikes me as a perfect candidate for a great chat discussion now that chat is an option on SD, if perhaps not an actual 'question'.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is to edit those that offer something of lasting value into actual questions. In this particular instance, the post would become:

> Where can I find sounds from the LHC?

You could go on by additionally asking if anyone knows what *kinds* of sounds a giant, high energy particle smasher tends to produce.

Then, move what was shared in the question into the answer itself. By doing this you've:

- Salvaged potentially useful information that would probably be deleted if closed
- Expanded the question so that even more answers might one day appear
- Taken ownership of the content

The third point is somewhat interesting, as you're basically moving someone else's question into an answer *you* are writing. This is what I'd recommend:

- Leave a comment and ask the user to make the question into a question, and move the information shared into an actual answer
- If no response, go ahead and do it, but provide special attribution at the top of your answer:

> Note: This information was originally put in the question. We've moved it to an answer in order to fit our Q&A format.

You can link to the first revision of the post in that text if you like. That brings us to the question of earning a modicum of rep for the trouble - and you should. Remember, rep is what makes the system give you more privileges, and if you're doing this kind of content maintenance, you *should* have access to more tools.

It's just a suggestion to get the discussion going. We definitely want to watch out for broken windows, and no - this wasn't a big problem for Social Sound Design. However, it's a question of .. do we want to improve the content we're in charge of curating, and that answer should generally be yes. You're just helping the author [share something, Q&A style](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

By the same token, we are a Q&A site, so questions *should* be questions. When it comes to the more 'pure fun' versions of these .. well, we'll see as they come up.

On another note - these are precisely the types of discussions I hoped would start, and good on you for starting it.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed that this should be a chat question. Perhaps people would have been more strict about this is SSD had a chat space. There are definitely many more examples of this sort of non-question.

Answer (score 1):

I was the person who flagged the question. I think it should be locked, a common fate for questions that were successful in the past but no longer reflect how new questions should be written.

EDIT: Meta.SO post about locked questions: [What is a "locked" post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post)

SO blog post about locking older questions: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/

Answer (score 0):

Since this type of question and others like it that have been more socially (getting to know the community) oriented have worked in the past for SSD, I think a decent compromise could be to allow questions that are social/community oriented as long as they are still clearly answerable and don't elicit debate or discussion.

I think such questions should be marked as community wiki so that they don't contribute to the reputation system and should also be given a "community" or "social" tag so that it is clear what they are and so that we can monitor if they are becoming too big of a portion of the site.  Seems like it gives a bit of the best of both worlds this way.